# ASP.NET - Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code Here:

```
var directories;

if (filePath == "")
{
    directories = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath);
}
else
{
    directories = Directory.GetDirectories(myPath);
}
```

But I get this error when defining the variable:

> Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized

Why am i getting this error and how would I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `var`, the compiler doesn't know what the type of `directories` is unless you initialize while you declare it. You have to declare a type if you're initializing later.

```
string[] directories;

if (filePath == "")
{
    directories = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath);
}
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use var without an assignment.  It is the assignment that determines the type of a var.  Just change to declare a specific type and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot figure out what type `directories` is because you did not initialize it.

Try this:

```
string[] directories;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that C# is strongly typed language. So compiler could not determine what `directories` is at compile time.

`var` keyword was introduced for [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) binding at compile time. So if you dont initilize the value of `directories` it is unknown to the compiler as at runtime the actual type(*value or reference*) is taken and `var` is nowhere in the picture.

So you can try like

```
string[] directories;

if (filePath == "")
{
    directories = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath);
}
```

or if you want to use var only then you can use it like this:

```
var directories = (string)null;

if (filePath == "")
{
    directories = Directory.GetDirectories(filePath);
}
```

You can also refer MSDN for details: [Implicitly Typed Local Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx)